# IPython Notebook session for Django

Tags: python, django, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to do web development using Django in an IPython Notebook?

If so, what are the best steps that you would need to take to accomplish that?

Comment: I was curious to know I think the opposite question. Is it possible to create a Django APP that can spin up an IPython session? For example host a web server where users can log into it and do IPython data analysis through the browser...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, creating a simple Django application in an IPython Notebook [has been tried before](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/agconti/Django-IPython-Tutorial/blob/master/django_tut.ipynb). But it is difficult due to the following reasons:

1. You will need to run the development server as a separate process. This makes it hard to read the log messages it outputs
2. Editing files is awkward. Commands like `%%writefile` will overwrite a file. I would prefer a command for adding diffs at the appropriate places.
3. Too often you will need to run shell commands like `manage.py` or `git`. This is OS specific and might not be portable.

While I prefer IPython as a shell for Django development, I didn't find IPython Notebook fitting into my workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If IPython itself enough and you do not need to have HTML-interactive notebook session you can run IPython and Django in the terminal.

With [django-extensions package](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org) you get [shell_plus](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shell_plus.html) command which runs interactive IPython interpreter against Django. It's like normal Django [shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#shell) command, but runs IPython instead of normal Python REPL.

However I am not sure can you hook

Comment: I believe you misinterpreted the request. The OP wants to write an ipython notebook that contains some django code (to e.g. write an interactive tutorial about django or something like that).